# Unable to read Css Styles and unable to load full HTML page in JSDF

Tags: jquery, jspdf

I am using JSPDF library to load the HTML page into PDF, I tried with sample small HTML page, it worked well but in my Application its not displaying the complete HTML page and not loading css styles. Please help me where i went wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
     $('#cmd').click(function () {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.getFontList();
            doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
                'width': 170,
                height: 30,

                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
        });  
    });
```

Comment: Can you give us the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the right syntax is  doc.fromHTML($('#target').get(0), ...

  - jspdf can't render your css